# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException when adding cell values to a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, indexoutofboundsexception

[image]

As above screenshot;

When user selects Item and Item Name and click Add button, below scenarios happen:

1. The selected Item,Item Name and cost retrieves from the MySQL database.
2. Show Input Dialog to get qty from the user.
3. After clicking OK to qty Input Dialog, Show Input Dialog to get Discount.
4. After clicking OK to discount Input Dialog,the total is calculated and shows in the total Column.

But then shows the `ArrayIndexOutOfBound` error as:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException: 1>=1
```

Then after selecting another Item and Item Name and doing the above process shows same error as:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException: 2>=2
```

Also reset Qty, Discount, Total columns to be equal as the last row values.

Add button action performed method;

```
private void add_btnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        int i=0;
        int j=0;
        String temp = (String) IDcombo.getSelectedItem();
        String temp2 = (String) Namecombo.getSelectedItem();

        String sql = "select ItemID,ItemName,CostPrice from druginfo where ItemID=?";
    try {   
        pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1, temp);

        rs=pst.executeQuery();

        addDataToTable(tableSale,DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));//this method for adding multiple lines in the table


        IDcombo.setSelectedItem(null);
        Namecombo.setSelectedItem(null);
        exptxt.setText(null);
        instock.setText(null);

      //getting user input for selling qty 
        String Qty=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Insert Selling Quantity :");
        double sellingqty=Double.parseDouble(Qty);

      //getting user input for specific item discount
        String discount = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Insert Item Discount");
        double idiscount=Double.parseDouble(discount);

       for(j=0;j<100;j++){
           double icost =(double) tableSale.getModel().getValueAt(j,2); 
        System.out.println(icost);

      //calculating Gross Total  
        double grosstotal = (sellingqty*icost)-idiscount;

        System.out.println(grosstotal);

        for(i=0;i<100;i++){
         //setting qty input value to table sale  
        tableSale.getModel().setValueAt(sellingqty,i, 3);
        //setting input value to table sale  
        tableSale.getModel().setValueAt(idiscount,i, 4); 
        //setting grosstotal value to table sale
        tableSale.getModel().setValueAt(grosstotal,i, 5); 
        }

       }


    } catch (Exception ex) {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "error "+ex);
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is the Stack Trace;

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 >= 1
at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:474)
at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.setValueAt(DefaultTableModel.java:664)
at com.bit.project.Newsale.add_btnActionPerformed(Newsale.java:720)

java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2 >= 2
at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:474)
at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.setValueAt(DefaultTableModel.java:664)
at com.bit.project.Newsale.add_btnActionPerformed(Newsale.java:720)
```

Comment: you have only 2 rows in your table .but you are trying to access 100 rows .why is that?for what this `for(i=0;i<100;i++){` loop ?

Comment: Idea is I can add until 100 rows... because Add button add new rows when clicked.. `for(i=0;i<100;i++){` is for setting the values tothe net row incrementally  @FastSnail

Comment: that for loop is always going to give you that `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: @tenten error `1 >= 1` mean there is only one row but you are accessing 1st index row mean 2nd row .but there is no 2nd row.you add new rows that's true but when you call `getValueAt()` the cell should exist

Comment: You may want to change those loop to something like:  `for(j=0; j< model.getRowCount(); j++)` . By the way, why are you doing those jobs in two nested for loops?

Comment: @STaefi `for(j=0;j<100;j++){` for getting relevant row's cost value. `for(i=0;i<100;i++){` for setting values to the relevant cells in relevant row.. If you know better solution, plz let me know :)

Comment: FastSnail did it before me :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove for loop and use this code

```
int i = jTable1.getRowCount()-1;
double icost = (double) tableSale.getModel().getValueAt(i, 2);
System.out.println(icost);

//calculating Gross Total  
double grosstotal = (sellingqty * icost) - idiscount;

System.out.println(grosstotal);

//setting qty input value to table sale  
tableSale.getModel().setValueAt(sellingqty, i, 3);
//setting input value to table sale  
tableSale.getModel().setValueAt(idiscount, i, 4);
//setting grosstotal value to table sale
tableSale.getModel().setValueAt(grosstotal, i, 5);
```

`java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 >= 1` mean there is only one row but you are accessing 1st index row that mean 2nd row .but there is no a 2nd row.you add new rows that's true but when you call `getValueAt()` the cell should exist

in my code

```
int i = jTable1.getRowCount()-1;
```

int i will get the last row index for example if there is only 1 row then i is 0 .so to get value from current row use `getValueAt(i, 2);` .same to `setValueAt();`

Comment: I changed like this `double icost = (double) tableSale.getModel().getValueAt(i , 2);` It works Thanks :) @Fast Snail